# Change all empty strings to NULL using one query with loop. SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have table with columns:
[1959], [1960], [1961] ... [2016];

All these columns are type nvarchar(255), some of these have empty strings ''. I want to change empty strings to NULL. I write query:

```
DECLARE @empty nvarchar(255);
SET @empty='';
DECLARE @cnt INT = 1959;
WHILE @cnt < 2017
BEGIN
   declare @sql nvarchar(1000)
   set @sql = 'UPDATE [HDProjEtap1Proba1].[dbo].[TESTGDP] SET [' + CAST(@cnt as nvarchar(255)) + '] = null WHERE ['+ CAST(@cnt as nvarchar(255)) +'] = ' + @empty;
   EXEC(@sql);
   SET @cnt = @cnt + 1;
END;
```

But dosn't work. Message error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>   Incorrect syntax near '='.

Can you tell me how do it right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@empty` is empty.  It doesn't represent the empty string when you concatenate it.

One simple solution is:

```
SET @empty = '''';
```

However, you can do the same thing by passing a parameter using `sp_executesql`.  And I like that approach:

```
declare @cnt INT = 1959;
while @cnt < 2017
begin
   declare @sql nvarchar(1000)
   set @sql = 'UPDATE [HDProjEtap1Proba1].[dbo].[TESTGDP] SET [' + CAST(@cnt as nvarchar(255)) + '] = null WHERE ['+ CAST(@cnt as nvarchar(255)) +'] = @empty';
   exec sp_executesql @sql, N'@empty nvarchar(255)', @empty = '';
   set @cnt = @cnt + 1;
end;
```

Or event:

```
declare @cnt INT = 1959;
while @cnt < 2017
begin
   declare @sql nvarchar(1000)
   set @sql = '
UPDATE [HDProjEtap1Proba1].[dbo].[TESTGDP]
    SET [@colname] = null
    WHERE [@colname] = @empty';

   set @sql = replace(@sql, '@colname', cast(@cnt as varchar(255));

   exec sp_executesql @sql, N'@empty nvarchar(255)', @empty = '';
   set @cnt = @cnt + 1;
end;
```

Notice that in this version, the SQL statement is easy to read (and hence to modify and debug).  It is defined with parameters that are then subsequently replaced.